# Replace laptop's usb surge protection chip

Tags: usb, identification, surge-protection, laptop

I am fixing an old laptop from 2008 (eMachine e525) on which everything works fine expect the 2 usb ports that are not powered.

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrVz4TRf5rU)¹ from Ingmar M. on youtube (very helpful video, thanks!) and I tried, like him, to desolder the 6 pin chip that is said by this user to be a surge protection component. Now the 2 ports are working fine.

I would like to know if I can replace this component so that I can safely plug usb devices. The problem is that I am not able to find a corresponding datasheet. The text on the tiny component reads (I think) "0635" on first line then "0926" on the second line. Orientation of the chip: the text is written alongside the longest dimension, if placed in reading position then the usb connectors are located north of it and there is an orientation dot in the south-west corner.

¹ Even if the video is about a e527 computer the motherboard looks identical to the one in my e525.

I used my multimeter in continuity mode to identify the pinout:
[image: Schematic of the 6 pin surge protection chip]

The 6 pin chip is visible in the center of the image:

[image: the chip is visible in the center of the image]

Here it is removed:
[image: chip unsoldered (the placeholder is visible in the center of the image)]

Comment: Might be an array of clamping diodes?  Check a supplier for those in a compatible package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chip is for protection of laptop against ESD. Functionally it is optional, the ports must be fully functional even is this chip is removed.

If you want to restore full protection, you need to search for "TVS" diodes on, say, Digi-Key database, select 6-pin devices, with proper package (based on pin pitch), and then look into each datasheet to find matching pinout. Your part looks pretty much as [IP4220](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/IP4220CZ6.pdf), just drawn upside down.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot! I would never have found the "TVS" keyword myself.